# ¿Por qué javascript me arroja undefined al tratar de accesar al método del objeto?

Tags: javascript, poo, funciones, undefined

Había un error donde javascript me decía que producto0PrecioConIva.descuentoUsuarios no era una función. Luego agregué producto0 al principio de esta instrucción pero ahora existe un error en la variable productoConDescuentoDeUsuario donde javascript me arroja undefined al tratar de accesar al método de descuentoUsuarios perteneciente al objeto Productos... no sé si esto será porque los parámetros de dicho método estarán mal implementados...

```
let descuentoParaUsuarios = 1000;
let nombre;
let entrada;

class Usuarios{
    constructor(id,nombre){
      this.id = id;
      this.nombre = nombre;
    }   
}

const usuario0 = new Usuarios(0,"Alex Argento");
const usuario1 = new Usuarios(1,"Bruno Días");
const usuario2 = new Usuarios(2,"Cosme Fulanito");
const usuario3 = new Usuarios(3,"Juan Pérez");



class Productos{
    constructor(idProducto,nombreProducto,precio){
        this.idProducto = idProducto;
        this.nombreProducto = nombreProducto;
        this.precio = precio;
    }
    sumarIva(){ 
      this.precio = this.precio * 1.21;
      return this.precio;
    }
    descuentoUsuarios(descuentoParaUsuarios){
        this.precio = this.precio -= descuentoParaUsuarios;
        return this.precio;
    }
}

const producto0 = new Productos(0,"Escudo del Capitán América",5000);
const producto1 = new Productos(1,"Disfraz de Superman",8000);
const producto2 = new Productos(2,"Disfraz de Ironman",30000);
const producto3 = new Productos(3,"Disfraz de la Mujer Maravilla",3333);


let producto0PrecioConIva = producto0.sumarIva(producto0.precio); 
let productoConDescuentoDeUsuario =producto0.producto0PrecioConIva.descuentoUsuarios(producto0.precio);


nombre = prompt("Por favor, ingrese su nombre de usuario");

function saludarUsuario(){
    alert("Hola." + nombre + "\n Bienvenido a MEM Cosplay");
    //Mem Cosplay es el nombre de la página de ventas que cree en 
    //La primera etapa de Desarrollo Web.
}

while(nombre == ""){
    alert("Lo siento, debe ingresar un nombre de usuario para continuar.");
    nombre = prompt("Por favor, ingrese su nombre de usuario");
}

saludarUsuario();


entrada = prompt("Te gustaría saber el precio del " + producto0.nombre + " con nuestro descuento de usuarios");

if(entrada == si || entrada == SI || entrada == sí || entrada == SÍ){
    alert(producto0PrecioConIva);
    alert("El producto: " + producto0.nombre + " sale " + producto0.precio + ", más el IVA sale: " + producto0PrecioConIva + ".\n Y con el descuento de usuarios quedaría en: " + productoConDescuentoDeUsuario);
    
}else if(entrada == no || entrada == NO){
    alert("No hay problema, regresa cuando quieras.")
}else{
    alert("ERROR: reinicie la página.");
}
```

Comment: Mirá esto: `producto0.producto0PrecioConIva`: ¿existe la propiedad `producto0PrecioConIva` en `Productos`? Leé y releé tu código. Hay varios errores, de hecho. Seguí analizando.

Comment: ajá @padaleiana tenés razón... eliminé producto0PrecioConIva de esa instrucción y logré hacer andar el algoritmo, pero luego en la pregunta aparecía Te gustaría saber el precio del "undefined" y me fijé que producto0.nombre se refería equivocadamente al nombre del usuario y no al del producto, entonces lo cambié a producto0.nombreProducto y funcionó la pregunta. Pero luego no quiso andar el condicional if pues no me aceptaba el si o el no cuando lo introducía, la consola arrojaba que "si is not defined" hasta que observé que los si y los no carecían de las comillas para poder ser un string.

Comment: luego anduvo el condicional tanto si introducía el si o el no, pero al introducir el si, aparecía el segundo alert con "el producto undefined sale en 0..." y logré observar que de nuevo producto0.nombre se refería equivocadamente al nombre del usuario y no al del producto, lo cambié como hice antes y funcionó pero llegué a un punto donde no sé por qué aparece en ese alert que el producto tal sale 0 y que con el descuento sale 0 también... de hecho trato de mostrar por consola producto0.precio y arroja efectivamente 0 y no se qué estoy haciendo mal, pues puedo accesar a las demás propiedades...

Comment: Observé también que los return de los métodos del segundo objeto Productos deberían ir es en la línea de arriba y no con this.precio, entonces eliminé esa línea en cada return y los coloqué donde deberían estar, justo al lado de las operaciones... pero sigo sin entender por qué no puedo mostrar producto0.precio ni tampoco resolver por qué el producto sale 0 y que con el descuento sale 0 en el alert... traté de accesarlo incluso tipo array como producto0.precio[2] y no me arrojó cero pero si undefined

Comment: Estás modificando el precio original (`this.precio`) en las funciones...